# Contribution form errors after latest security release

Tags: civicontribute

We have three different clients reporting erratic errors on public-facing and administrative credit card donation forms.

The error is that CiviCRM reports that a credit card + expiry is invalid, and the error shows up before talking to the payment processor, i.e. it's form error, not a payment processor error. We've confirmed that the cc credentials are in fact valid.

These started happening after the latest (Nov 20 2019) security update (some on the 5.13.7, some on 5.19.2, not all using the same payment processor).

See attached picture for a clue: note the title of the cc images.

[image: contribution form]

Answer (score 5):

So the error occurs when CiviCRM is doing it's implementation of the Luhn algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm

The picture suggests it's javascript related, but note that there are no console errors showing.

Fix: I cleared both the site cache and the browser cache and now it works.

The weird [object Object] title that you can see in the console seems to be a red herring.

In our case, the issue is likely due to css/js/img resources having long caches and not getting cleared by CiviCRM with the upgrade, so restarting Varnish in front of the site is likely the right answer.